# Removing each model from a backbone.js collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to iterate through a backbone collection and move each item to another collection.
While iterating through and removing items only half the items are removed.

```
app.cloud.each(function(model){
    app.cloud.remove(model);
    app.tail.add(model);
})
```

Can anyone suggest a nice way of addressing this issue? Ideally I wan't to keep the code as readable as possible.

Answer (score 3):

You're modifying the collection as you're iterating over it.  I don't know backbone very well, but I venture to say that this will produce weird results.

A possible fix is to change your approach so that first you add everything to `app.tail` by iterating over `app.cloud` and then clear `app.cloud`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the reason for wanting to move all models to a new collection but... I'd suggest not iterating over it yourself - let Backbone take care of it. I haven't tried the following but should work.

```
app.tail.add(app.cloud.toJSON());
app.cloud.reset();
```

To be safer you'd want to **reset** app.cloud when the **add** event fires in app.tail.